# How to mask parent div with child div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mask, clip

There's a continuous background tile in the parent, like so:

```
#parent{
    background: url('tile-bg-under-menu.png') repeat-x center 32px;
    height: 151px;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Then, I have the child, that is above the parent with another image, like so:

```
#parent .child {
    background: url('menu-bg.png') no-repeat 50% 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 170px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

So, I would like to `hide` the exact portion of the `#parent` div that is behind the `.child` div in the width and height of the `#parent` div.
I'm looking for something like the inverse of `clip` or anything that would work the same (masking the parent with the child).

**The reason for the question:**

The reason I ask this is because: the `.child` div has a semitransparent background, that has a portion that is overlapping `#parent` "horizontal tile" which is also semitransparent; so when they meet, their semitransparent portions cover/intersect each over at that part, which is ugly, and that is not part of the graphical plan.

**EDIT**: I can't use jpg, because the divs are floated above a "dynamic" content.

I tried to:

- make a `::before` and `::after` work-around, outside them, **but** I couldn't get the content (background tile) to reach to the ends of the browser window.
- make a png that is 4k in width and empty exactly at the portion where the `.child` is present. This was not as bad idea as it sounds, **but** with this there is a pixel movment to the left or to the right according to differing browsers.

The solution can be either with **CSS** or **JavaScript** - it doesen't matter.

It seems that there is no equivalent to an inverse clipping: [Is there an inverse to the CSS "Clip" property; hide the clipped area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078262/is-there-an-inverse-to-the-css-clip-property-hide-the-clipped-area)

Clarification:

The div part looks something like this:

[(`#parent`)tile part]{[-here curve down`.child` overlapping part]here curve up-}[(`#parent`)tile part]

The demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/13k2hn9y/
And the snippet:

```css
header{
  position: fixed  
}

/*#masthead */
    /*top: 25px;*/
#parent { 
    background: url('https://ladyfx.ae/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/upper-menu-bg.png') repeat-x center 8px;
    height: 151px;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
/*.header-wrap*/
#parent .child {
    background: url('https://ladyfx.ae/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/menu-bg.png') no-repeat 50% 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 170px;
}
#parent, #parent .child{
pointer-events: none;
}
#parent .child .container{
pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 
 <header id="parent" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="child"><!-- .header-wrap -->
  </div>
 </header><!-- #masthead -->

 
 <div class="content">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at dui in quam placerat aliquet. In semper lectus sed lectus iaculis blandit. Etiam egestas ex ac rhoncus commodo. Praesent sagittis eget ante nec interdum. Suspendisse tempus est ac libero rhoncus, laoreet pulvinar mi sagittis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent quis tincidunt ipsum. Mauris nec arcu mollis, pellentesque nisi vitae, gravida sem. Duis vel velit vel lectus rhoncus luctus a vitae nulla. Nunc nec enim sapien. Quisque tempus dolor at viverra pharetra. Vivamus molestie bibendum sapien, vitae iaculis nisl fringilla euismod. Integer quis tincidunt ligula, at vulputate risus.

In vitae purus nec massa viverra mattis quis id lacus. Pellentesque cursus sapien nec tortor faucibus, sit amet sodales tortor faucibus. Aliquam pulvinar sollicitudin urna, ac suscipit sapien venenatis quis. Morbi eu risus in massa pretium molestie. Fusce rhoncus orci in ornare consectetur. Sed volutpat tristique nibh congue finibus. Integer semper sagittis sem vitae varius. Sed sit amet tellus in justo dictum fringilla. Pellentesque dignissim congue nulla non tincidunt. Etiam tempor ante metus, vel pretium est dapibus at.

Etiam eu consequat leo, sit amet placerat ex. Nullam sit amet lectus turpis. Curabitur ac euismod mauris, quis semper ex. Proin efficitur, odio nec tempus blandit, mauris nisl commodo turpis, a tempor lectus purus quis ex. Aliquam id ipsum risus. Mauris quis massa ut dui porttitor pharetra. Nulla aliquam tellus vitae odio rutrum efficitur. Vivamus accumsan iaculis augue, sit amet dignissim turpis aliquam sed.

Quisque finibus fringilla est vitae lobortis. Duis quis egestas nunc, vel ultricies velit. Sed blandit dolor erat, eu placerat tellus ornare dictum. Suspendisse suscipit, tortor ut auctor facilisis, lacus nisl tempor nunc, non mollis nibh velit ut elit. Duis vel laoreet quam, sit amet egestas diam. Fusce aliquam dignissim ante id bibendum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus gravida, augue at consequat mattis, diam nisl porta enim, in gravida dui tortor et tortor. Phasellus elit lacus, luctus sit amet neque id, lobortis placerat est. Donec ac tristique mi. Nulla facilisi. Aenean interdum dictum turpis laoreet vestibulum.

Morbi scelerisque, eros auctor euismod consectetur, justo diam dapibus est, id placerat neque dui ut lorem. Fusce in orci egestas, semper libero id, porta tortor. Etiam nec quam et mauris commodo posuere. Duis gravida, libero nec hendrerit venenatis, lacus felis congue ante, eget rutrum justo turpis quis massa. Donec eget magna vitae dui consequat bibendum. Morbi porta dignissim urna, eget mattis lacus commodo vel. Nunc ligula ex, suscipit in accumsan ut, laoreet eu felis. Morbi sem felis, luctus at lorem a, lobortis vulputate nulla. Duis cursus mi eget arcu placerat consequat. Curabitur venenatis consectetur varius. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam dapibus id ex id commodo.

Donec pretium leo magna, eu viverra lacus vehicula quis. Vivamus vel risus in ligula tristique feugiat ac eu erat. Nulla commodo augue a tortor iaculis varius. Maecenas id facilisis libero. Sed semper, lorem at vulputate tristique, odio ipsum condimentum mi, a volutpat dolor nisi vel risus. Pellentesque at gravida nisi, in vehicula orci. Sed vestibulum aliquam vestibulum. Ut mattis ligula in dolor eleifend, id ultrices sapien lobortis. Suspendisse sed blandit augue. Phasellus et efficitur mauris. In ac urna auctor, hendrerit mauris sed, dictum tortor. Duis nec diam interdum, hendrerit nisi ac, interdum diam. Vivamus fringilla risus nec lacus ullamcorper rutrum. Proin ac pellentesque risus.

Nunc interdum pretium feugiat. Fusce id bibendum turpis, tincidunt iaculis neque. Vestibulum at enim lobortis, venenatis magna eget, commodo est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec ipsum eget tellus efficitur auctor vitae eu augue. Etiam nec diam velit. Morbi vel pretium sapien. Suspendisse tempus faucibus orci, ut rutrum sem tincidunt a. Mauris at lorem tellus.

Nunc est velit, tristique suscipit interdum at, mollis non arcu. Sed imperdiet leo quis eleifend laoreet. Pellentesque dapibus at massa pulvinar eleifend. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam elementum placerat est nec dapibus. Nulla libero erat, mattis sed rutrum eget, molestie posuere nibh. Etiam in ex ut lorem auctor pretium. Curabitur eget scelerisque libero, a scelerisque libero. Fusce vel rutrum mauris, in elementum ligula. Vestibulum nisi lectus, blandit quis risus vitae, aliquet lobortis orci.

Pellentesque vel est vitae tellus porta sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer vulputate eleifend pellentesque. Integer vel vehicula tellus. Etiam ut euismod orci, vel venenatis massa. Quisque sit amet ipsum vitae metus mollis cursus hendrerit at neque. Nunc cursus eu urna vitae efficitur. Praesent et accumsan felis. Integer maximus condimentum mi eget consequat. Nulla in nulla ullamcorper, vestibulum sem in, ultricies dolor. Vivamus eleifend auctor magna quis varius. Cras lacinia ornare volutpat. Proin porttitor lacus eget convallis mattis. Cras at urna libero. Donec est nisl, commodo in enim ut, dictum molestie neque.

Vivamus sit amet sagittis diam. Sed finibus laoreet lectus, eu rutrum tortor ullamcorper nec. Mauris finibus justo eu tellus pharetra, vel mollis diam venenatis. Aliquam hendrerit nec dolor eget blandit. Nullam id velit ac mauris malesuada dictum quis a dui. Proin nec molestie lectus. Aenean blandit tempus nisl eget scelerisque. Etiam aliquam lorem id quam pretium, quis ullamcorper ex finibus. Donec vulputate condimentum eleifend. Aenean ac consectetur sem. Aenean id eleifend diam. Suspendisse imperdiet sodales tincidunt.

Proin venenatis, tellus sed volutpat interdum, lacus mauris elementum nibh, id commodo lectus lorem vitae sem. Curabitur eget mauris massa. Curabitur viverra egestas consectetur. Donec enim ex, pharetra vitae justo nec, blandit accumsan ipsum. In ac mauris non magna imperdiet facilisis eu a leo. Nunc ipsum lacus, sollicitudin a ipsum non, commodo sagittis nibh. Cras pharetra vehicula enim at consequat.

Ut efficitur mollis erat a placerat. In feugiat mauris eu maximus tincidunt. Donec ut neque a erat vulputate aliquam in et elit. Sed eu est eu mauris rutrum auctor nec et odio. Etiam sapien purus, cursus et hendrerit vitae, fermentum non quam. Aenean a nibh eget tellus rutrum ornare. Etiam imperdiet massa convallis, commodo neque vel, tincidunt elit. Sed et varius turpis, vitae malesuada sem. Nam eu sollicitudin est. Phasellus semper sem at congue vestibulum. Phasellus nisi mi, facilisis vitae lorem et, placerat volutpat sem. Sed feugiat sapien malesuada purus sodales, sit amet faucibus dolor feugiat. Aenean nulla risus, elementum id magna a, pulvinar efficitur felis.

Proin imperdiet enim massa, at sollicitudin libero laoreet vel. Fusce euismod libero at aliquam commodo. Donec tempus enim a pretium consequat. Mauris nec fringilla purus. Aliquam in interdum augue, sed efficitur massa. Vivamus vel erat accumsan, rhoncus urna posuere, feugiat nibh. Sed efficitur magna neque, id tincidunt mauris iaculis sit amet. Nunc maximus auctor est, vitae tristique metus. Integer dapibus risus ligula, nec volutpat est maximus gravida. Praesent tempus consequat augue, et pharetra libero placerat eleifend. Curabitur congue dictum ipsum. In vitae lorem vitae orci vulputate molestie.

Mauris id elit accumsan, molestie elit et, mollis ipsum. Fusce dapibus nisi eget vestibulum pellentesque. Fusce vel tortor at mauris aliquet placerat eu non lacus. Sed vestibulum auctor ligula, sed posuere urna congue ut. Integer et molestie elit. Curabitur aliquam suscipit dui eu elementum. Fusce sollicitudin, sem ut finibus finibus, turpis enim efficitur urna, nec aliquam urna elit vitae justo. Morbi nec lectus neque. Integer aliquet est eget pharetra blandit. Maecenas tortor quam, porta vel egestas ac, consequat in lectus. Cras lacinia lectus tellus, quis varius metus molestie sed. Quisque gravida eleifend sem cursus tincidunt. Sed eget orci non nisi tempor tempus sit amet vel felis. Pellentesque quis ex sed mi ultricies tincidunt a eget velit. Phasellus finibus eget massa eleifend posuere.

Vestibulum pellentesque tellus vel bibendum eleifend. Phasellus vitae mauris leo. Nunc ut orci fringilla, maximus urna nec, cursus quam. Etiam egestas, tortor sit amet ornare dignissim, augue ante imperdiet metus, sed volutpat lacus orci congue felis. Etiam convallis mi quis ex laoreet tincidunt. Phasellus vitae turpis id magna posuere ornare. Duis et malesuada mauris, in ultricies nunc. Phasellus non felis mollis, pretium lectus id, sagittis nisi. Nullam volutpat leo ut turpis aliquet blandit. Quisque ut felis mi.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas hendrerit eros vel ipsum placerat maximus. Nunc sed vestibulum risus, quis porta est. Phasellus consequat fringilla quam, ac elementum ligula mollis a. Maecenas facilisis lectus et ornare sodales. Nullam sed rutrum urna, nec volutpat quam. Etiam iaculis a sapien eu euismod. Morbi tempus, ligula ac facilisis scelerisque, quam purus consectetur mauris, vitae iaculis quam purus ut felis. Suspendisse consectetur lobortis velit, sed ultricies purus. Curabitur erat leo, volutpat non dapibus id, pretium at lorem. Quisque accumsan purus sit amet volutpat dapibus. Vestibulum malesuada ipsum in ipsum consectetur blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer in est tincidunt, lobortis odio et, ultrices ligula. Suspendisse tempus quis nisl in efficitur. Nunc in leo cursus, interdum sapien ut, porta est.

Morbi a arcu quis libero pretium lobortis. In nisl tortor, ullamcorper fermentum elit ut, vestibulum vestibulum tortor. Maecenas vitae libero a lorem commodo blandit eget id erat. Mauris ac ultrices dolor. Mauris volutpat magna sit amet diam consequat, in lacinia lorem iaculis. Phasellus et urna augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Vestibulum at risus sit amet sem elementum efficitur in eu lectus. Curabitur at turpis at ante sagittis dapibus id nec turpis. Pellentesque placerat lectus eget mauris tincidunt, ut porta velit faucibus. Nunc sed malesuada ex, in mattis dolor. Nam ac purus laoreet, aliquet lorem quis, posuere libero. In suscipit est ornare congue auctor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus nec eleifend justo. Nam ut dapibus mi, quis scelerisque velit. Sed nec lectus egestas, sollicitudin ante ac, bibendum massa. Curabitur nec volutpat purus.

Cras sed ligula ut ipsum tincidunt mollis. Sed egestas tellus erat, vel porta nulla facilisis eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempor lorem et neque auctor euismod. Nam ac interdum turpis. Vivamus placerat ipsum nec nibh laoreet efficitur. Curabitur fringilla vestibulum nibh ut euismod. In suscipit rutrum aliquet. Vivamus non euismod velit, sit amet cursus elit. Cras ultricies velit sed tellus ullamcorper, eu auctor leo euismod. Donec at ultrices est. Cras mollis justo eu interdum suscipit.

Vivamus eleifend justo id diam posuere dictum. Aliquam posuere, orci dapibus lacinia eleifend, tellus neque consequat diam, eu laoreet sem lacus quis libero. Curabitur rhoncus at sem non feugiat. Maecenas blandit imperdiet leo sit amet euismod. Vivamus rutrum eleifend lectus sit amet pellentesque. Pellentesque sodales nunc a odio faucibus pretium gravida eu ligula. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum vel ultricies malesuada. Aenean eget lobortis justo, in posuere enim. Praesent rutrum porta metus, sollicitudin maximus risus semper eu. Sed volutpat tincidunt lectus, ac scelerisque massa rhoncus in. Mauris eget augue venenatis, ultricies turpis ac, finibus odio. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas lobortis vehicula dolor, vitae congue ligula ultrices id. Integer vitae lacus in mauris finibus varius nec sed est. 
  
   </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I understand it as you want the child to cover whatever is behind it, why don't you just use a jpg for the child instead? or set a background colour for the child

Comment: @Huangism I can't use jpg, because the div is floated above the content, it would be ugly.

Comment: You said you want to cover the parent with your child, is this not the case? Create a simplified demonstration ad post it here so we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok, it is perfectly normal for the menu to cover the content of the page. I don't understand the issue. You can't set a background colour for the child either? You could always try to set a translucent bg colour

Comment: @Huangism I'll update the question, but this is not the case. The div is not only floating it has a part of image that is overlapping the content. A few minutes...

Comment: You will have to show an example of this, let me know when you update the question

Comment: @Huangism I've tried to clarify the question, but this is all the time I have now. I will be back after about two hours.

Comment: When you have time, post an example with actual html and css, you can use https://jsfiddle.net or snippet on here to demonstrate

Comment: @Huangism I've updated my question with the snippet and the fiddle. Please, take a look.

Comment: I see it, it looks fine other than the extra shadows on the logo. So based on the fiddle, what are you trying to do? The overlapping shadow part ?

Comment: @Huangism Not only the extra shadow that bothers me, but where the two images intersect they add an extra "shadow". I would like **to mask the parent div with the child div**!

Comment: Yea that overlap creates the darker shadow, you can do this with flex https://jsfiddle.net/13k2hn9y/4/ is that good? the logo is not perfect center, because your logo image is not symmetrical

Comment: @Huangism Wow! Thank you so much! :-) That's Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with display flex, see code below

I moved the background image for the parent to the 2 spacer children. With the logo being the child in the middle. I set the spacers to `flex-grow: 1` so they will expand the width.

Your logo image currently, needs to be properly centered (edit the image so it is symmetrical)

If you want to learn more about flex read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
header{
  position: fixed
  
}

/*#masthead */
    /*top: 25px;*/
#parent { 
    display: flex;
    height: 151px;
    width: 100%;
    
}
/*.header-wrap*/
#parent .child {
    background: url('https://ladyfx.ae/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/menu-bg.png') no-repeat 50% 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 553px;
}
#parent, #parent .child{
pointer-events: none;
}
#parent .child .container{
pointer-events: all;
}

.spacer {
  background: url('https://ladyfx.ae/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/upper-menu-bg.png') repeat-x center 8px;
    height: 151px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 
 <header id="parent" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="spacer">
    
    </div>
  <div class="child"><!-- .header-wrap -->
  </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    
    </div>
 </header><!-- #masthead -->

 
 <div class="content">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at dui in quam placerat aliquet. In semper lectus sed lectus iaculis blandit. Etiam egestas ex ac rhoncus commodo. Praesent sagittis eget ante nec interdum. Suspendisse tempus est ac libero rhoncus, laoreet pulvinar mi sagittis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent quis tincidunt ipsum. Mauris nec arcu mollis, pellentesque nisi vitae, gravida sem. Duis vel velit vel lectus rhoncus luctus a vitae nulla. Nunc nec enim sapien. Quisque tempus dolor at viverra pharetra. Vivamus molestie bibendum sapien, vitae iaculis nisl fringilla euismod. Integer quis tincidunt ligula, at vulputate risus.

In vitae purus nec massa viverra mattis quis id lacus. Pellentesque cursus sapien nec tortor faucibus, sit amet sodales tortor faucibus. Aliquam pulvinar sollicitudin urna, ac suscipit sapien venenatis quis. Morbi eu risus in massa pretium molestie. Fusce rhoncus orci in ornare consectetur. Sed volutpat tristique nibh congue finibus. Integer semper sagittis sem vitae varius. Sed sit amet tellus in justo dictum fringilla. Pellentesque dignissim congue nulla non tincidunt. Etiam tempor ante metus, vel pretium est dapibus at.

Etiam eu consequat leo, sit amet placerat ex. Nullam sit amet lectus turpis. Curabitur ac euismod mauris, quis semper ex. Proin efficitur, odio nec tempus blandit, mauris nisl commodo turpis, a tempor lectus purus quis ex. Aliquam id ipsum risus. Mauris quis massa ut dui porttitor pharetra. Nulla aliquam tellus vitae odio rutrum efficitur. Vivamus accumsan iaculis augue, sit amet dignissim turpis aliquam sed.

Quisque finibus fringilla est vitae lobortis. Duis quis egestas nunc, vel ultricies velit. Sed blandit dolor erat, eu placerat tellus ornare dictum. Suspendisse suscipit, tortor ut auctor facilisis, lacus nisl tempor nunc, non mollis nibh velit ut elit. Duis vel laoreet quam, sit amet egestas diam. Fusce aliquam dignissim ante id bibendum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus gravida, augue at consequat mattis, diam nisl porta enim, in gravida dui tortor et tortor. Phasellus elit lacus, luctus sit amet neque id, lobortis placerat est. Donec ac tristique mi. Nulla facilisi. Aenean interdum dictum turpis laoreet vestibulum.

Morbi scelerisque, eros auctor euismod consectetur, justo diam dapibus est, id placerat neque dui ut lorem. Fusce in orci egestas, semper libero id, porta tortor. Etiam nec quam et mauris commodo posuere. Duis gravida, libero nec hendrerit venenatis, lacus felis congue ante, eget rutrum justo turpis quis massa. Donec eget magna vitae dui consequat bibendum. Morbi porta dignissim urna, eget mattis lacus commodo vel. Nunc ligula ex, suscipit in accumsan ut, laoreet eu felis. Morbi sem felis, luctus at lorem a, lobortis vulputate nulla. Duis cursus mi eget arcu placerat consequat. Curabitur venenatis consectetur varius. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam dapibus id ex id commodo.

Donec pretium leo magna, eu viverra lacus vehicula quis. Vivamus vel risus in ligula tristique feugiat ac eu erat. Nulla commodo augue a tortor iaculis varius. Maecenas id facilisis libero. Sed semper, lorem at vulputate tristique, odio ipsum condimentum mi, a volutpat dolor nisi vel risus. Pellentesque at gravida nisi, in vehicula orci. Sed vestibulum aliquam vestibulum. Ut mattis ligula in dolor eleifend, id ultrices sapien lobortis. Suspendisse sed blandit augue. Phasellus et efficitur mauris. In ac urna auctor, hendrerit mauris sed, dictum tortor. Duis nec diam interdum, hendrerit nisi ac, interdum diam. Vivamus fringilla risus nec lacus ullamcorper rutrum. Proin ac pellentesque risus.

Nunc interdum pretium feugiat. Fusce id bibendum turpis, tincidunt iaculis neque. Vestibulum at enim lobortis, venenatis magna eget, commodo est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec ipsum eget tellus efficitur auctor vitae eu augue. Etiam nec diam velit. Morbi vel pretium sapien. Suspendisse tempus faucibus orci, ut rutrum sem tincidunt a. Mauris at lorem tellus.

Nunc est velit, tristique suscipit interdum at, mollis non arcu. Sed imperdiet leo quis eleifend laoreet. Pellentesque dapibus at massa pulvinar eleifend. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam elementum placerat est nec dapibus. Nulla libero erat, mattis sed rutrum eget, molestie posuere nibh. Etiam in ex ut lorem auctor pretium. Curabitur eget scelerisque libero, a scelerisque libero. Fusce vel rutrum mauris, in elementum ligula. Vestibulum nisi lectus, blandit quis risus vitae, aliquet lobortis orci.

Pellentesque vel est vitae tellus porta sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer vulputate eleifend pellentesque. Integer vel vehicula tellus. Etiam ut euismod orci, vel venenatis massa. Quisque sit amet ipsum vitae metus mollis cursus hendrerit at neque. Nunc cursus eu urna vitae efficitur. Praesent et accumsan felis. Integer maximus condimentum mi eget consequat. Nulla in nulla ullamcorper, vestibulum sem in, ultricies dolor. Vivamus eleifend auctor magna quis varius. Cras lacinia ornare volutpat. Proin porttitor lacus eget convallis mattis. Cras at urna libero. Donec est nisl, commodo in enim ut, dictum molestie neque.

Vivamus sit amet sagittis diam. Sed finibus laoreet lectus, eu rutrum tortor ullamcorper nec. Mauris finibus justo eu tellus pharetra, vel mollis diam venenatis. Aliquam hendrerit nec dolor eget blandit. Nullam id velit ac mauris malesuada dictum quis a dui. Proin nec molestie lectus. Aenean blandit tempus nisl eget scelerisque. Etiam aliquam lorem id quam pretium, quis ullamcorper ex finibus. Donec vulputate condimentum eleifend. Aenean ac consectetur sem. Aenean id eleifend diam. Suspendisse imperdiet sodales tincidunt.

Proin venenatis, tellus sed volutpat interdum, lacus mauris elementum nibh, id commodo lectus lorem vitae sem. Curabitur eget mauris massa. Curabitur viverra egestas consectetur. Donec enim ex, pharetra vitae justo nec, blandit accumsan ipsum. In ac mauris non magna imperdiet facilisis eu a leo. Nunc ipsum lacus, sollicitudin a ipsum non, commodo sagittis nibh. Cras pharetra vehicula enim at consequat.

Ut efficitur mollis erat a placerat. In feugiat mauris eu maximus tincidunt. Donec ut neque a erat vulputate aliquam in et elit. Sed eu est eu mauris rutrum auctor nec et odio. Etiam sapien purus, cursus et hendrerit vitae, fermentum non quam. Aenean a nibh eget tellus rutrum ornare. Etiam imperdiet massa convallis, commodo neque vel, tincidunt elit. Sed et varius turpis, vitae malesuada sem. Nam eu sollicitudin est. Phasellus semper sem at congue vestibulum. Phasellus nisi mi, facilisis vitae lorem et, placerat volutpat sem. Sed feugiat sapien malesuada purus sodales, sit amet faucibus dolor feugiat. Aenean nulla risus, elementum id magna a, pulvinar efficitur felis.

Proin imperdiet enim massa, at sollicitudin libero laoreet vel. Fusce euismod libero at aliquam commodo. Donec tempus enim a pretium consequat. Mauris nec fringilla purus. Aliquam in interdum augue, sed efficitur massa. Vivamus vel erat accumsan, rhoncus urna posuere, feugiat nibh. Sed efficitur magna neque, id tincidunt mauris iaculis sit amet. Nunc maximus auctor est, vitae tristique metus. Integer dapibus risus ligula, nec volutpat est maximus gravida. Praesent tempus consequat augue, et pharetra libero placerat eleifend. Curabitur congue dictum ipsum. In vitae lorem vitae orci vulputate molestie.

Mauris id elit accumsan, molestie elit et, mollis ipsum. Fusce dapibus nisi eget vestibulum pellentesque. Fusce vel tortor at mauris aliquet placerat eu non lacus. Sed vestibulum auctor ligula, sed posuere urna congue ut. Integer et molestie elit. Curabitur aliquam suscipit dui eu elementum. Fusce sollicitudin, sem ut finibus finibus, turpis enim efficitur urna, nec aliquam urna elit vitae justo. Morbi nec lectus neque. Integer aliquet est eget pharetra blandit. Maecenas tortor quam, porta vel egestas ac, consequat in lectus. Cras lacinia lectus tellus, quis varius metus molestie sed. Quisque gravida eleifend sem cursus tincidunt. Sed eget orci non nisi tempor tempus sit amet vel felis. Pellentesque quis ex sed mi ultricies tincidunt a eget velit. Phasellus finibus eget massa eleifend posuere.

Vestibulum pellentesque tellus vel bibendum eleifend. Phasellus vitae mauris leo. Nunc ut orci fringilla, maximus urna nec, cursus quam. Etiam egestas, tortor sit amet ornare dignissim, augue ante imperdiet metus, sed volutpat lacus orci congue felis. Etiam convallis mi quis ex laoreet tincidunt. Phasellus vitae turpis id magna posuere ornare. Duis et malesuada mauris, in ultricies nunc. Phasellus non felis mollis, pretium lectus id, sagittis nisi. Nullam volutpat leo ut turpis aliquet blandit. Quisque ut felis mi.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas hendrerit eros vel ipsum placerat maximus. Nunc sed vestibulum risus, quis porta est. Phasellus consequat fringilla quam, ac elementum ligula mollis a. Maecenas facilisis lectus et ornare sodales. Nullam sed rutrum urna, nec volutpat quam. Etiam iaculis a sapien eu euismod. Morbi tempus, ligula ac facilisis scelerisque, quam purus consectetur mauris, vitae iaculis quam purus ut felis. Suspendisse consectetur lobortis velit, sed ultricies purus. Curabitur erat leo, volutpat non dapibus id, pretium at lorem. Quisque accumsan purus sit amet volutpat dapibus. Vestibulum malesuada ipsum in ipsum consectetur blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer in est tincidunt, lobortis odio et, ultrices ligula. Suspendisse tempus quis nisl in efficitur. Nunc in leo cursus, interdum sapien ut, porta est.

Morbi a arcu quis libero pretium lobortis. In nisl tortor, ullamcorper fermentum elit ut, vestibulum vestibulum tortor. Maecenas vitae libero a lorem commodo blandit eget id erat. Mauris ac ultrices dolor. Mauris volutpat magna sit amet diam consequat, in lacinia lorem iaculis. Phasellus et urna augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Vestibulum at risus sit amet sem elementum efficitur in eu lectus. Curabitur at turpis at ante sagittis dapibus id nec turpis. Pellentesque placerat lectus eget mauris tincidunt, ut porta velit faucibus. Nunc sed malesuada ex, in mattis dolor. Nam ac purus laoreet, aliquet lorem quis, posuere libero. In suscipit est ornare congue auctor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus nec eleifend justo. Nam ut dapibus mi, quis scelerisque velit. Sed nec lectus egestas, sollicitudin ante ac, bibendum massa. Curabitur nec volutpat purus.

Cras sed ligula ut ipsum tincidunt mollis. Sed egestas tellus erat, vel porta nulla facilisis eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempor lorem et neque auctor euismod. Nam ac interdum turpis. Vivamus placerat ipsum nec nibh laoreet efficitur. Curabitur fringilla vestibulum nibh ut euismod. In suscipit rutrum aliquet. Vivamus non euismod velit, sit amet cursus elit. Cras ultricies velit sed tellus ullamcorper, eu auctor leo euismod. Donec at ultrices est. Cras mollis justo eu interdum suscipit.

Vivamus eleifend justo id diam posuere dictum. Aliquam posuere, orci dapibus lacinia eleifend, tellus neque consequat diam, eu laoreet sem lacus quis libero. Curabitur rhoncus at sem non feugiat. Maecenas blandit imperdiet leo sit amet euismod. Vivamus rutrum eleifend lectus sit amet pellentesque. Pellentesque sodales nunc a odio faucibus pretium gravida eu ligula. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum vel ultricies malesuada. Aenean eget lobortis justo, in posuere enim. Praesent rutrum porta metus, sollicitudin maximus risus semper eu. Sed volutpat tincidunt lectus, ac scelerisque massa rhoncus in. Mauris eget augue venenatis, ultricies turpis ac, finibus odio. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas lobortis vehicula dolor, vitae congue ligula ultrices id. Integer vitae lacus in mauris finibus varius nec sed est. 
  
   </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :-) But, I just cut the image for this purpose of the example, the image in the actual site is different.

Comment: Yea, this just gives you the proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need. utilizing css `position` property

```css
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    background-image: url('src-to-image');
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.overlay > img {
    position: relative;
    /**use top and left property to even cover more specify areas**/
    display: inline-block;
    /**set width, height property to specify coverage dimensions*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```